# Trying to run Insert with SqlParameters with EF, getting scalar variable error, How to fix?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am using EF 6 with MVC5/C#

I am trying to run an insert statement, using `SqlParameter` objects, via `ExecuteStoreCommand` over EF. I am doing it this way as I have some performance issues with `AddObject`.

My code is:

```
string insertCmd = "INSERT INTO TABLE (Value,FkId) VALUES (@Value,@FkId)";

var paramList = new[]{
    new SqlParameter("@Value", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = value,
    new SqlParameter("@FkId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = fkId
};

db.ExecuteStoreCommand(insertCmd, paramList);
```

I am getting the error:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@Value". Statement(s) could not be prepared.

I have noticed that it always complains about the first column in the Insert statement regardless of type. So if I swapped it around I would get:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@FkId". Statement(s) could not be prepared.

Thoughts ?

EDIT:

Just noticed that the record gets inserted and saved to the DB, yet I still get this error. Puzzled...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look really carefully at the type inferred by the compiler for the variable:

```
var paramList = new[]
{
    new SqlParameter("@Value", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "SomeValue",
    new SqlParameter("@FkId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 123
};
```

You'll see that `paramList` is a an `Object[2]` with the two scalar values `Value(string)` and `123(int)`, and the `SqlParameters` are lost altogether, because the result of an assignment is the assigned value! `Object` is inferred by the compiler as the lowest common denominator of `string` and `int`.

Unfortunately the call to [`ExecuteStoreCommand`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.objects.objectcontext.executestorecommand?view=netframework-4.7.2) won't give you any warning that you aren't passing `SqlParameter[]`, since it accepts the very weak type `params object[]` as per the docs:

> The parameters value can be an array of DbParameter objects or an array of parameter values

To solve this, you can either use one of the `SqlParameter` constructors which take on the value directly, e.g.

```
var paramList = new[]
{
    new SqlParameter("@Value", "SomeValue"),
    new SqlParameter("@FkId", 123)
};
```

Or create the parameters, assign them, and then add to the array.

Out of interest, `ExecuteStoreCommand` is a method on [`ObjectContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.objects.objectcontext.executestorecommand?view=netframework-4.7.2), not DbContext.

There's an equivalent method [`DbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.database.executesqlcommand?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) which should do the same thing.

Comment: Just tried your first suggestion, and it worked. Really love your very comprehensive reply. I see the Object Type now ! So grateful.